# how to check which unit test has covered specific line of code in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mstest

How to check which unit test has covered specific line of code in visual studio

e.g.

My solution has multiple class libraries.

I am analyzing code coverage for all tests from Test menu in VS.

For some methods, it is showing green, which means that code is covered in unit testing.

```
public void someclassMethod()
{
  _service.Method();
}
```

I want to check unit tests for this _service.Method() (which is marked as green means covered code)

Is there any way to find out which code is covered in which unit test project?

Comment: Only by running each test separately, as far as I know.

Comment: This is a documentation work that the arch or responsable has to do. Or improve the UT design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CodeLens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2022#associated-unit-tests)  feature shows the method that tests the related method.

e.g. : [SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tifjT.png)

I use VS Enterprise 2019 but Community Edition included CodeLens features. [CodeLens features - VS 2022 Community Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2022)

To activate it you need to:

- Click Tools > Options
- Toggle open Text Editor
- Toggle open All Languages
- Click CodeLens
- Click Enable CodeLens

  - Show Test Status CheckBox
- Then click OK